# how to send template class arguement in friend function of a plain class

Tags: c++, templates

My code is written below

```
template<class t>
class stack{
        private: t val;
                 stack *next;
        public:  stack(t);
                 //void push(stack &st);
                 //void traverse();
};
class pstack{
  public:
        static pstack *top;
        friend void push(stack &,pstack *);  //This line is not working
};
```

"stack" is template class and "pstack" is a non-template class. In "pstack" class "push" is a friend function taking arguement an object of template class "stack".

Please help me in getting this push functin correct.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the `push` function a template as well:

```
class pstack{
  public:
        static pstack *top;

        template<typename T>
        friend void push(stack<T> &,pstack *);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare your friend as a template as well:

```
class pstack{
  public:
        static pstack *top;
        template <class T> friend void push(stack<T> &,pstack *); 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

class templates need to be instantialized before use. so in your function declaration, you need to add a template type argument to `stack`.

`friend void push(stack<Type> &, pstack *);`